# PHP creating video from string data

Tags: php, string, video, base64

I'm trying to create a PHP web service for an android application which send a video as a string data and images as a string data both are base64 encoded to that PHP web service
So I create the image from the string as the following:

```
protected function saveImage($data, $image_ext, $path){
    if(!empty($data)){
        $data = base64_decode($data);
        $im   = imagecreatefromstring($data);
        if ($im !== false) {
            $name = 'img-'.str_random(4).'.'.$image_ext;
            if ($image_ext == "png"){
                imagepng($im, $path . $name, 9);
            }else{
                imagejpeg($im, $path . $name, 100);
            }

            return $path.$name;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

Now I need to do that to the video string, is there any way to do that 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a way to do that I can only set the header to video/xxx and xxx = video type the use file_put_contents php function to store the video at the desired path

```
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
$data = base64_decode($data);
$name = $path.'video-'.str_random(4).'.mp4';
$target_file = base_path()."/public/".$name;
file_put_contents($target_file,$data);
```

base_path() here to get the application root path at laravel